# search_data method not working with Searchkick reindex

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch

I have a search_data method in one of my Searchkick-enabled models, but it doesn't look like Searchkick is honoring it when asked to reindex.

Here's my model (abridged):

```
class Archive < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick

  def search_data
    {:creator=>self[:creator],:description=>self[:description],:pdf=>self.pdf_contents,:title=>self[:title]}
  end

  def pdf_contents
    Yomu.read(:text,File.read(path_to_file))
  end
end
```

In Rails Console, `Archive.first.search_data` returns what I expect: an object with attributes for creator, description, pdf, and title. However, `Archive.first.reindex` throws an error saying it can't parse the dateacquisitioned field. The ActiveRecord object (Archive.first) does have a dateacquisitioned attribute, but as you can see it's not in the list of attributes in the search_data method. So why is Searchkick's reindex method trying to index the dateacquisitioned attribute when I haven't asked it to?

Answer (score 0):

Tire (which powers Searchkick) calls `to_hash` in its reindex method.

https://github.com/karmi/retire/blob/197325b4e7adfef3def5db187733c4530bd7dfed/lib/tire/index.rb#L317